# How to pass params as variables inside methods like "dig"

Tags: ruby, methods, hash, parameters

I have a hash like:

```
my_hash = {"one"=>{"two"=>{"three"=>"four"}}}
```

I'd like to do:

```
my_hash.dig("one", "two")
=> {"three"=>"four"}
```

It's ridiculous to hardcode the params every time and it's obvious to use a variable like:

```
my_var = "one", "two"
```

Unfortunately, output is not great at all:

```
my_hash.dig(my_var)
=> nil
```

Why is this not working and how do I do it right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use array elements as individual parameters you'll have to use the [splat operator](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Array+to+Arguments+Conversion) (`*`).

```
my_hash = {"one"=>{"two"=>{"three"=>"four"}}}
my_var = "one", "two" # same as: my_var = ["one", "two"]

my_hash.dig(*my_var)
#=> {"three"=>"four"}
```

```
# The above could be read as:
my_hash.dig(*my_var)
my_hash.dig("one", "two")

# While your version can be read as:
my_hash.dig(my_var)
my_hash.dig(["one", "two"])
```

The reason your version outputs `nil` is because objects (like arrays) can be used as hash keys. Your version is looking for the key `["one", "two"]`, which is not present in `my_hash`. Thus returning the default value `nil`.

Comment: Just a note that `dig` should only be used when a `nil` return value is a valid possibility. If, for example, the hash is known to have the form `h = {"one"=>{"two"=>{"three"=>"four"}}}` with known nested keys, `h.dig("one", "tow", "three")` silently returns `nil` (because `"two"` has been misspelled). By contrast, `h["one"]["tow"]["three"] #=> NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass)`, which is what we would want in this case.